# How do I use the maximum function in the pulp package restrictions

Tags: python, pulp

I'm writing linear programming using the pulp package from python. I have doubts about building a constraint.

To illustrate the problem, imagine a square measuring 100 x 100 cm. I have several circles with varying dimensions. I need to include these circles in the square in order to maximize the sum of the diameter area. When the first row is filled, the second will be formed above it and so on, always considering as a constraint:

Each circle can only be selected once in each row
The sum of the diameter of the circles cannot exceed the length limit
The sum of the diameter of the circles cannot exceed the width limit
The sum of the area of the circles cannot be greater than the area of the square
My doubt is in constraint 3. My idea is to identify the maximum diameter of each row (it could be the average too). The sum of these maximums cannot exceed the value of 100. Is it possible to create such a constraint?

'Variables'

```
alocado = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("alocado", 
                        ((n, t) for n, t in df.index),
                        cat='Binary')

model = pulp.LpProblem("Alocacao_na_pilha", pulp.LpMaximize)
```

'Objective Function'

```
model += pulp.lpSum(alocado[n, t] * df.loc[(n, t), 'area'] 
            for n, t in df.index),'z'
```

'Set'

```
circle= df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
filled= df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()
```

'Restrictions'

```
for n in circle:
    model += pulp.lpSum(alocado[(n, t)] for t in filled) <= 1

for t in filled:
    model += pulp.lpSum(alocado[(n, t)] * df.loc[(n, t),'d1'] for n in circle) <= 100

model += pulp.lpSum(pulp.lpSum(alocado[n, t] for t in filled) * df.loc[(n, t), 'area'] for n in circle) <= 1000
```

'Solving the problem'

```
model.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(maxSeconds=1000, msg=1, fracGap=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the input data in your question I can't implement it directly but setting a constraint on the sum of the maximums of each row should be fairly easy. Solution below in pseudo-code.

The way I would do it would be to introduce a new set of variables - one for each row:

`row_maxes = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("row_maxes", [i for i in range(n_rows)], cat='Continuous')`

You then need to constraint these variables to be at least as big as the largest circle on each row:

```
for i in range(n_rows):
    for circle in i:
        prob += row_maxes[i] >= circle.diameter
```

You can then set whatever constraint you want on the sum of these row_maxes:

`prob += lpSum([row_maxes[i] for i in range(n_rows)]) <= 100`

We are relying here on the fact that the objective is to fit in as many circles as possible. In our constraints on each of the `row_maxes` we only have to set the constraint on one side - but it's the side that we care about for the sake of fitting the circles in.